# CPU frequency limited when AC adapter is on, but no limit with battery

Tags: power-management, performance, battery, cpu, frequency

Here I got a strange problem with my ThinkPad X200.

This notebook uses Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU P8600, which has a designed frequency of 2.4GHz. When I use battery only, the maximum scaling frequency can be 2.4GHz, **HOWEVER, when I insert the AC adapter, the frequency is limited to 1.6GHz.**

The problem still exists even I have disabled cpufreqd, and **forced the governor to performance.**

That's so weird! Would anybody have an idea?

P.S. My kernel version is 4.19.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, no one cares my problem, that's a tremendous pity.

However, luckily, I lave found a solution to deal with it!

What limits the CPU's maximum frequency? BIOS!

The file `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/bios_limit` tells the limitation value of BIOS.

On condition that `performance` governor is activated, when I use battery only, the value of `bios_limit` is 2400000, the maximum of the hardware. However, when I connect AC adapter, this value will soon lower to 1600000.

By default, Linux's governor follows `bios_limit`, so the problem occurs. But we can let Linux to ignore it, and don't let the maximum frequency stucks. Just set `ignore_ppc` to 1.

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/module/processor/parameters/ignore_ppc
```

And modify `/etc/default/grub` to automatically set `ignore_ppc` on reboot. Open it with root privilege, attach `processor.ignore_ppc=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, just like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash processor.ignore_ppc=1"
```

then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot.

References:

- [Permanently change maximum CPU frequency](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340626/permanently-change-maximum-cpu-frequency)
- [Maximum CPU frequency stuck at low value](https://askubuntu.com/questions/303882/maximum-cpu-frequency-stuck-at-low-value)
- [I cant set the cpu frequency to maximum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/899255/i-cant-set-the-cpu-frequency-to-maximum)

Comment: didn't work for me :( I've found a file called ``ignore_tpc`` and I don't have any ``bios_limit`` file ! Is it normal ?

Comment: Didn't work for me on Ubuntu 18.04, Dell Precision M5520.  And I also have no file `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/bios_limit`

Comment: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1350470/173693)'s what did work on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an **option in BIOS**. according to this image: 
[BIOS of ThinkPad X200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rf6WB.jpg)

I hope i help you.
Best regards.

Comment: My X200 doesn't have this option.

Comment: You're running your laptop without a battery? Only plugged with the adapter? In this case i mean it can be the cause.

Comment: No, I have a battery.

Answer (score 0):

*TLP* would come handy in such situations

```
sudo apt-get install tlp
```

And check the config file `/etc/tlp.conf`
or *tlpui* graphical interface

which might give you a clearer idea on your cpu performance limits under AC/BAT

```
#CPU_SCALING_MAX_FREQ_ON_AC 
#CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_AC
#CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_AC
#CPU_BOOST_ON_AC
...
```